# Posterior of Normal with prior Cauchy

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian

> Let $X\sim N(\theta,1)$ and $\pi(\theta)\sim \mathrm{Cauchy}(0,1)$ find a 90%
>   credible set for $\theta$

To find the credible set I need to find the distribution of $f(\theta\mid x)$, but
$$f(\theta\mid x)\propto \pi(\theta)f(x\mid\theta)$$
$$\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\theta)^2}\frac{1}{\pi(\theta^2+1)}$$
$$\propto e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\theta)^2}\frac{1}{(\theta^2+1)}$$

I tried to do some manipulations but I get nothing.

I would like to know if exists a analytical derivation, or it just can be obtained computationally through a software

Comment: Do you want an analytical derivation for the credible interval? Note that with the use of mathematical software like R (studio's) you can easily construct a $90\%$ credible interval.

Comment: @Siron  I would like to know if exists a analytical derivation.

Comment: The conjugate prior for a normal is a normal, so I don't think a neat formula exists. Also, note that you have not calculated the normalizing constant in your derivation.

Comment: To find a credible interval you have to specify the distribution of the posterior. In this case, that is not easy and I'm not even sure it is possible This is also the reason I mentioned the use of software such as R. You can then use a simple algorithm to generate (for example) 10^5 observations from the posterior (without knowing its distribution, so only using the prior and likelihood). From these generated values you can directly find an empirical 90% credible interval.